# Верна ли пунктуация, мною нарисованная?

Tags: пунктуация

> Я сидела с идиотской улыбкой и играла с ними <обитателями дельфинария>,
>   даже не знаю сколько времени, пока не опомнилась: зачем вообще сюда
>   пришла?

Перед "даже"?

Предложение оканчивалось точкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед `даже` запятая явно не лишняя.

Однако, по моему мнению, `Я сидела` и  `даже не знаю сколько времени`, как минимум, в данном предложении тяжеловато воспринимаются читателем. Не лучше ли будет разделить это предложение на два более простых следующим образом:
`Я всё сидела с идиотской улыбкой и продолжала играть с ними. Даже не знаю сколько времени прошло, пока не опомнилась, зачем вообще сюда пришла.`

Comment: Нет, Иван, автору можно только намекнуть, если ошибка неявная, что, к примеру, разбив предложения, мы облегчим читательское восприятие. Писать за него - нельзя. И обсуждать с ним каждое слово тоже не представляется возможным.

Comment: В таком случае, как я писал, запятая перед `даже` поставлена верно. P.S.: Если бы не вопросительный знак в конце предложения, то возможно ещё, что вместо двоеточия следовало бы поставить запятую.

Comment: Ванечка, нужны доказательства... ))) *Играла не знаю сколько времени* не требует запятой. Как "Улица Гоголя не скажете где?". Однако ж не уверена, а Вы делитесь со мной всего лишь мнением вместо правила.